# Upload de imagens e insercao do link das imagens numa base de dados

Tags: php, image

So i upload an image, but it doesn t save the link of the image, and doesnt send it to a database... and this error appears in my browser:" Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on resource"

```
 <?php


  echo "ola <br>";
  $host="localhost"; // Nome do host onde esta o banco de dados. Padrão ‘localhost’ 
  $usuario="root"; // Usuário do Mysql. Padrão ‘root’
  $senha=""; // Senha do Mysql 
  $db ="centro"; // Nome da Database 
  $tabela="usuarios"; // Nome da tabela

  //connecta ao servidor
$mysqli = mysql_connect("$host", "$usuario", "$senha")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");

if(isset($_POST["upload"]))
{
  //Nao vai buscar o $d para o link da imagem
  $mysqli=ligabd();

  $d="imagens/" . $_FILES["uploaded"]["name"];
  if($_FILES["uploaded"]["type"]=="image/jpeg")
  {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded"]["tmp_name"],$d))
    {
      echo '<img style="width:50px;height:50px;" src="'. $d . '" >';
    }
  }
  $titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
  $mensagem=$_POST['mensagem'];
  $ano=$_POST['ano'];
  $mes=$_POST['mes'];
  $dia=$_POST['dia'];
  $link=$d;
}
else
{
  echo "So imagens JPG.";
  $titulo=" ";
  $mensagem=" ";
  $ano=0;
  $mes=0;
  $dia=0;
  $link=" ";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO imagens(titulo,mensagem,dia,mes,ano,link) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stat = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stat->bind_param('ssiiis',$titulo,$mensagem,$dia,$mes,$ano,$link);

if ($stat->execute() && $stat->affected_rows>0)
{
  echo "<div>Foi inserida uma imagem!</div>";
}
$stat->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `mysql` in the below lines.

```
$mysqli = mysql_connect("$host", "$usuario", "$senha")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");
```

change this to `mysqli`,

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("$host", "$usuario", "$senha")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");
```

Comment: Now it doenst get the uploaded... the image link
in the browser it says:"Notice: Undefined index: uploaded"

Comment: @Leonoliveira check the element name in the form.

Comment: i checked and its the same